# Compressed representation of polygons

Tags: algorithm, geometry, compression, computational-geometry

I have a lot of (millions) of polygons from openstreetmap-data with mostly (more than 99%) exactly four coordinates representing houses.

**Example**[image: Example]

I currently save the four coordinates for each house explicitly as Tuple of floats (Latitude and Longitude), hence taking 32 bytes of memory.

**Is there a way to store this information in a compressed way (fewer than 32 byte) since the four coordinates only differ very few in the last decimals?**

Comment: I guess maybe an *implicit* grid structure would be what you want; store the data as if they are organised in some arbitrarily scaled grid, with small enough cells that you can store the coordinates with reasonable resolution, and then maybe a global scaling parameter.

Comment: This is a single map -- the elements come in in random order and are not sorted in any way. Best solution would be to only take in consideration the data stored on the polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your map patch is not too large, you can store relative coordinates against some base point (for example, bottom left corner). Get these differences, norm them by map size like this:

```
   uint16_diff  = (uint16) 65535 * (lat - latbottom) / (lattop - latbottom)
```

This approach allows to store 16-bit integer values.

For rectangles (you can store them in separate list) there is a way to store 5 16-bit values instead of 8 values - coordinates of left top corner, width, height, and angle of rotation (there might be another sets of data, for example, including the second corner)

Combining both these methods, one might get data size loss upto 3.2 times

Comment: My map patch is -- unfortunately -- very large (Europe). That's why I'm actually looking for a way to compress this data.

Comment: Is this single map, or it is composed from rectangles? Perhaps you could group objects by proximity in different lists with corresponding base point.

Comment: This is a single map -- the elements come in in random order and are not sorted in any way. Best solution would be to only take in consideration the data stored on the polygon.

Comment: But for showing a piece of map you need to get only objects in view region. It is worth to organize data in some space partitioning structure - it is needed for fast work.

Comment: It's not used to draw a map. I need to hold all data in memory to run some stastics and transformations on them. Some of the polygons might be transfered further via network. So the information should really be selfcontained without any meta-information of a grid.

Comment: Ok -- togeher with Ripi2's comment I got it -- We use one absolute coordinate for each house and store the others as relative coordinates. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @MBo said, you can store one corner of each house and compress the other three corners as relative to the first corner.

Also, if buildings are so similar you can set a "dictionary" of buildings. For each building you store its index in the dictionary and some feature, like its first corner coordinates and rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving no information on the resolution you want to keep.

Assuming 1 m accuracy is enough, 24 bits can cover up to 16000 km. Then 8 bits should also be enough to represent the size information (up to 256 m).

This would make 8 bytes per house.

More aggressive compression for instance with Huffman coding will probably not work on the locations (relatively uniform distribution); a little better on the sizes, but the benefit is marginal.

Comment: I need to keep the full float-resolution to be able to compare two coordinates later and detect them as "same".

Comment: @user2033412: rounded coordinates will also compare to equal. The double precision representation ensures a resolution of close to 4 Ångström for the whole Earth. Do you have data that accurate ?

Comment: I store the latitude and longitude in two floats.

Comment: @user2033412: there is something misleading in your description. You said 32 bytes for 4 coordinates ?!

Comment: Each coordinate constists of two floats (latitude, longitude) hence taking up 8 bytes of memory. Since I have four coordinates for each house this sums up to 4 x 8 bytes = 32 bytes.

Comment: @user2033412: then say "coordinate pair".

Comment: With floats, the effective resolution is close to the meter. Drop the floats and switch to (24 bits) integers, the exponent is of no use.

Comment: I love that idea! :-)

Comment: But within which type could I store this information (with bit fiddling)? I want to effectively take up less than eight bytes (two floats) for each coordinate-pair.

Comment: @user2033412 A byte array can do.

Comment: A byte-array will have overhead. I already have that problem, see here: [Efficient small byte-arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958396/efficient-small-byte-arrays-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @user2033412: I didn't know it was C#. Then a struct of bytes.

Comment: Very nice suggestion with the struct! Awesome idea.

Comment: @user2033412: you can also mix bytes and shorts, that can speed-up conversions to and from plain integers.

Comment: Even better! :-)

Comment: In 24bit I can only have a resolution of 40000km/(2^24) = 2,3 meters? :-(

Comment: Right, but this is exactly what you get with floats !

Comment: If you mix bytes and shorts, make sure to master the alignment/padding issues.