# Efficient small byte-arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, memory, encoding, compression

I have a huge collection of very small objects. To ensure the data is stored very compactly I rewrote the class to store all information within a byte-array with variable-byte encoding. Most instances of these millions of objects *need only 3 to 7 bytes to store all the data*.

After memory-profiling I found out that these byte-arrays *always take at least 32 bytes*.

**Is there a way to store the information more compactly than bit-fiddled into a byte[]? Would it be better to point to an unmanaged array?**

```
class MyClass
{
    byte[] compressed;

    public MyClass(IEnumerable<int> data)
    {
        compressed = compress(data);
    }

    private byte[] compress(IEnumerable<int> data)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private IEnumerable<int> decompress(byte[] compressedData)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> Data { get { return decompress(compressed); } }
}
```

Comment: I added the code. I have to store a few very small integers -- hence the variable-byte-encoding.

Comment: It's seems to be a "problem" related to the way you're creating the array before populating it. Can you provide the compress method source code?

Comment: Part of your problem is object overhead, which is even worse in a 64 bit build. This has some information about that: [Of Memory and Strings](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings/)

Comment: The array is fine -- I actually contains exactly the length I expect. It's the memory profiler that tells me that my byte[]-array of length 3 effectively takes up 32 byte in memory.

Comment: @hatchet: I already read that very interesting article -- that's why I'm asking for a more efficient way (maybe pointer to unmanaged byte-array?)

Comment: It might be simple, and use less memory to just use longs for your little objects, without bothering to make a class. You could write extension methods for packing/unpacking. That will avoid object overhead.

Comment: Or you could define a struct that has just one member that is a long value, and have methods for packing/unpacking in that struct.

Comment: I like that idea -- I could derive two types from an abstract base: One for small elements (less or equal to eight bytes) and one for bigger elements (more than eight bytes) -- both sharing the same interface from the abstract base.

Comment: Is this in 32-bit or 64-bit? In 64-bit an object takes 24 bytes at a minimum. An array is going to store the length in a field as well so that's 4 bytes for an int. I'm not surprised the runtime would allocate another 4 bytes (instead of the requested 3) just to make it fit in a nice round number like 32 bytes.

Comment: The application is 64 bit.

Comment: Try to not use arrays and instead use C# fixed buffers instead, see if that offers any hope? How many objects do you typically have? how long are the arrays?

Comment: @Hugh: The arrays are mostly 3 to 7 bytes long and I have millions of objects.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems you're facing that eat up memory. One is object overhead, and the other is objects aligning to 32 or 64 bit boundaries (depending on your build). Your current approach suffers from both issues. The following sources describe this in more detail:

- [Of Memory and Strings](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings/)
- [How much memory does a C# string take up](http://blog.abstractpath.com/2012/08/how-much-memory-does-c-string-take-up.html)

I played around with this when I was [fiddling with benchmarking sizes](http://blog.softwx.net/2013/01/benchmarking-c-struct-and-object-sizes.html).

A solution that is simple would be to simply create a struct that has a single member that is a long value. Its methods would handle packing and unpacking bytes into and out of that long, using shift and mask bit fiddling.

Another idea would be a class that served up objects by ID, and stored the actual bytes in a single backing `List<byte>`. But this would get complicated and messy. I think the struct idea is much more straightforward.

Comment: I though a lot about a big backing-array and only storing indexes -- but like you said: It's going to be messy.